# Assign singleton vector value to a single not yet defined variable in Dyalog APL

Tags: apl, dyalog

Dyalog APL allows assigning a vector of *multiple* values to a corresponding number of *multiple* not yet defined variables:

```
      x y←1 2
      ]display x
 
1
 
      ]display y
 
2
```

How to assign a *single* value from a *single-element* vector to a *single* not yet defined variable?

What I tried:

```
      (⊂x)←,1
VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: x
      (⊂x)←,1
        ∧
      (,⊂x)←,1
VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: x
      (,⊂x)←,1
         ∧
      (,x)←,1
VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: x
      (,x)←,1
        ∧
```

This works, but it is too dirty:

```
      (x x)←,1
      ]display x
 
1
```

The singleton vector is obtained as *one of* results of a function, and I want to avoid an additional `←⊃` statement after calling the function.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid an additional `⊃`? The code `x←⊃MyFunction arg` isn't bad.

Comment: Depending on the use case, it might be appropriate to build the  ⊃ into the defined function (if there is one).

Comment: Adam, the function returns *several* results. And kind of `foo bar x←{(⊃⍵)(2⊃⍵)(⊃3⊃⍵)}MyFunction` is also not nice. :)

Comment: Paul, enhancing the function is worth considering, of course, but it could cause massive refactoring, so I'd like to check whether an easier way exists first.

Comment: @Olexa Could `foo bar x←⊃@3⊢MyFunction` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
x _ ← ,1
```

While this might also be considered a "workaround", I think it's the cleanest and a similar pattern is fairly common in other programming languages, like the ML family (SML, Ocaml, Haskell), Python, JavaScript...